# High-performance hashing without collisions?

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography

The Hashing function below was borrowed heavily from [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed), but it has too many collisions in my application.

```
public static class Hashing
{
  private const int FNV1a_offsetBias = unchecked( ( int )0x81_1c_9d_c5 );
  private const int FNV1a_prime = 16_777_619;

  public static int FNV1a(params dynamic[] values) {
     var hash = FNV1a_offsetBias;

     foreach ( var value in values )
        hash = FNV1a_Crank(hash, value.GetHashCode());

     return hash;
  }

  private static int FNV1a_Crank(int start, int addendum) {
     unchecked {
        start *= FNV1a_prime;
        start += addendum;
     }

     return start;
  }
}
```

I need high-performance hashing that is guaranteed unique. I realize it will likely need to be slower than the function above, but I'm hoping to find something that is not dramatically slower. The SE post linked above is fascinating and useful, but also leaves me confused and wondering what to use.

**The use case for my hashing is this:** I have an app that inserts millions of records every day into my database. The tables being inserted into contain unique keys and thus any insert that violates uniqueness will throw an exception. I cannot allow these exceptions to be thrown because it's far too slow, and it's just better to avoid for other reasons. So I use the function above to hash the column values in the composite unique key of each insert and store in a hash table. Before each insert, I generate a hash and look for the hash in the hashtable. If it's not there, then I'm safe to do the insert. If it is there, the record already exists, and I skip the insert.

It's very fast, and I thought it worked at first. But then I found dozens of cases (out of millions) in which hashes collide and thus my app believes a record had already been inserted--when in fact it hadn't. So I get missing records, which is unacceptable to the business.

Here are a few examples of the sort of data I am hashing:

```
Hasher("Z125",  "99-8ZG10", "SpecialZ_S07181_2");
Hasher("G125");
Hasher("G99-76", "F78_XYZ_92323");
```

**So I'm looking for a c# function that provides the fastest possible hashing algorithm that is guaranteed unique.** In other words, I need a performant way to check millions of times *does this record already exist in the table*? Hashing seems like the fastest way, but uniqueness is paramount.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using a 32-bit hash code then clearly you can't have more than 2^32 unique hash codes. If the thing you're hashing can have more than 2^32 possible states then it is impossible to uniquely hash it.

Comment: Every hash function is guaranteed to be not unique given unbound input...

Comment: Asking it more broadly, what is the fastest way to store/lookup uniqueness?

Comment: Generally what you do is this: Does the collection contain the hash code? If not, then it *definitely* doesn't contain the item. Otherwise, it *may* contain the item, and you need to check if it does. This is still a lot faster, since you can reject many lookups via the O(1) hash lookup.

Comment: Watch this on probability of collisions: https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/

Can you extend hash value to more than 32bit?

Comment: Emanuele: how can I modify my posted function to achieve 1 in 100 trillion? Can you give me a code example?

Comment: Can you try to use long instead of int?

Comment: You could also use IGNORE_DUP_KEY to have duplicate keys not produce an error and be ignored instead, so you don't have to deal with an exception. Insert your record and if it was a duplicate it won't do anything instead.

Comment: You need to take a step back and look at the number dimensions. With 32 bits, you can uniquely identify 4294967295 "things". So if you're working with "millions" of entries, there shouldn't be a problem. When you get into "billions", you'll run into the pidgeonhole problem real soon. "100 trillion"? No way with a 32 bit value. With a 64 bit value, you can uniquely identify 18446744073709551615 "things". Much more breathing room.

Comment: Longoon I am excited about IGNORE_DUP_KEY and running some tests now...if it works performantly, it is THE solution for me.

Comment: Note: Even if IGNORE_DUP_KEY works I'll still need a good hashing solution for my 2nd use case that I didn't mention: ensuring that a related record (FK) exists so that FK constraint isn't violated. IGNORE_DUP_KEY won't solve that one.

Comment: Emanuele, what  code changes are needed besides changing the `ints` to `longs`?

Comment: I'm reminded of a conversation I once had with a superior who asked if I could solve a certain problem. Me:"Sir, that would be impossible because the laws of physics say so". Superior: "Never mind theory, can you do it in practice?". You can't have a collision-free hash function. You might be able to define a one-to-one function from your domain to a 32-bit int, provided that your domain contains <= 2\**32 elements. If your domain contains more than 2\**32 elements then it's impossible according to laws of mathematics.

Comment: What Einstein proved, Newton would have called a violation of math and physics. Looking for an Einstein. [I am not him.]

Comment: Longoon, `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` has solved my problem. I never knew this even existed. Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest reading about the [birthday problem/paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).  given a 32bit hash you can expect to get collisions after around 64k values, i.e. much earlier than you're apparently expecting.  a good/equidistributed 64bit hash would only be useful for around 2**32 unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your goal is to generate a unique identifier for your database records. Usually your database system will allow you to set a primary key for your database records, which the system will then ensure is unique across the database. Such primary keys are generally enough for many applications. However, there are several other things to consider, such as:

- Whether identifiers have to be hard to guess, or merely "look random".
- Whether identifiers are the only thing that grants access to the record.

The best way to generate unique identifiers will depend on these and other questions, which I give in the section "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)". You should edit your question post with the answers to the six questions I give in that section; the answers will further suggest what kind of identifiers to use. However, if you can't tolerate the risk of duplicate identifiers, as in this case, then neither random numbers nor hashes of column values are appropriate as unique identifiers unless the application checks them for uniqueness.

Comment: I went down a different path: IGNORE_DUP_KEY in mssql was the best solution for me, but it's kinda way off from what I asked - so, thank you Peter.